# How to add Automator Folder Action from command line

Tags: mojave, automator, catalina

Is there a way to add `Folder Action` to Automator tool from the command line?

When I typed `Automator` I get very basic CLI options (-D, -i, -v)..
Can someone please add an example of how to do it?

Comment: The `automator` tool just runs an Automator workflow.  If you are asking about creating an Automator folder action, you will need to use the Automator application.

Comment: @red_menace is there any cli way to create a workflow?

Comment: The Automator application does have extensive AppleScript support, so it may be possible to create a workflow using an AppleScript. But.. can you explain why you need to automate the creation of an Automator workflow?

Answer (score 1):

See [Attaching a Folder Action using Applescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38879240) for an AppleScript, an Open Scripting Architecture (OSA) language, solution. You can use `osascript` on the command line to run OSA scripts:

> Your syntax was OK in old versions (at least up to macOS 10.6.8). Since it has been depreciated and it must be replaced by "make" :
>
> ```
> tell application "System Events"
>     make new folder action at end of folder actions with properties {enabled:true, name:"FolderName", path:"path:to:my:folder}
>     tell folder action "FolderName" to make new script at end of scripts with properties {name:"myScriptName.scpt"}
> end tell
> ```